# Memory leak in Swift Combine sink

Tags: swift, memory-leaks, combine

Xcode Instruments detects memory leak in this simple Combine example:

```swift
import Combine
import Foundation

func main() {
    print("Start")

    let publisher = CurrentValueSubject<Bool, Never>(false)
    var cancellable: AnyCancellable? = publisher
        .prefix(1)
        .sink(receiveValue: { _ in })

    cancellable?.cancel()
    cancellable = nil

    Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 10.0)         // wait for Instruments to make leak snapshot

    print("End")
}

main()
```

Memory leak is detected in `sink` call:

```
   0 libsystem_malloc.dylib posix_memalign
   1 libswiftCore.dylib swift_slowAlloc
   2 Combine Publishers.Output.Inner.__allocating_init(downstream:range:)
   3 Combine Publishers.Output.receive<A>(subscriber:)
   4 Combine Publisher.subscribe<A>(_:)
   5 Combine Publisher<>.sink(receiveValue:)
   6 CombineLeak1 main() .../main.swift:24
   7 CombineLeak1 main .../main.swift:34
   8 libdyld.dylib start
```

If such publisher is flatmapped, it produces memory leak for every event.
If the operator `prefix(1)` is replaced by `first()`, memory leak disappear. What is wrong?

*Note: Instruments was run properly via Profile build with Release configuration.*

Comment: It's a leak, but it's extremely small. I wouldn't worry about it. Anyway it's not your doing. You could file a bug with Apple of course.

Comment: If you flatmap such Publisher, it could accumulate extremely.

Comment: The leak is 16 bytes. Not megabytes. Not kilobytes. Bytes. Do you have any idea how much stuff would have to come down the pipeline for you to notice that?